# can compensation disclosure to other employees be a basis for dismissal in quebec?

Tags: employment, canada, labor-law, quebec

Can sharing or discussing you compensation with your colleagues be a reason for being fired or be a basis for any other decision by the employer?

I know there are rules in Ontario against this but I couldn't find anything in Quebec labor law.

Answer (score 1):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The *Fair Work Act* prohibits an employer from making remuneration confidential. That  is, any employee can disclose their salary to anyone.